# MYSQL: Can you pull results that match like 3 out of 4 expressions?

Tags: mysql

Say I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = "john doe" AND phone = "8183321234" AND email = "johndoe@yahoo.com" AND address = "330 some lane";
```

But say I only need 3 out of the 4 to match, I know I can write a very long query with several ORs but I was wondering if there was a feature for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM 
  my_table 
WHERE 
  CASE WHEN name = "john doe"           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN phone = "8183321234"        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN email = "johndoe@yahoo.com" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN address = "330 some lane"   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  >= 3;
```

Side note: this will very likely not be using indexes efficiently. On the other hand, there will very likely be no indexes on these kinds of columns anyway.

Comment: I think it will suffice to just sum the comparison expressions as they themselse always return 0 or 1: `name="john doe" + phone="12345" + email="john.doe@example.com" + address="123 some lane" >= 3`.

Comment: Yes, that does it on MySQL, I guess. Nevertheless I like explicitness better, and a comparison operation does not necessarily return a numerical value on other systems.

Comment: Hm... I wonder why this keeps catching down-votes. Is it wrong or is this just opinion voting?

Comment: Well, yeah. You could argue that it is cleaner and shorter. I would hardly call my solution "overcomplex" though. It's correct, not performing any worse *and* it would run on almost any other SQL environment there is. Frankly, I don't see a good reason to down-vote, but there you go.

Comment: Well, I'd say it is at the very least flirting with over complexity, especially when there's a much shorter way of doing it. That being said, I've removed my downvote, because I guess you could also make the argument chaos' solution is not very clear to someone that doesn't understand how the comparisons get evaluated into 1s. :)

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino: "especially when there's a much shorter way of doing it" is a very Perlesque view on the world. ;-) I am used to XSLT and ColdFusion, so verbosity does not drive me away. I'm rather verbose than implicit any time, even in environments where I don't have to.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should have said 'holy thundering sesquipedalian verbosity, Batman'.  If someone doesn't understand numeric evaluation of boolean expressions, though, they should be able to infer it pretty quickly from the existence of my example. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: "sesquipedialian" = "1,5 feet long", from Horace's "Ars Poetica"

Comment: @Quassnoi: My Google Translate already told me. :) I just like the word a lot, never saw it before. That's one detail I love about the English language - it never stops to surprise and amuse me.

Comment: That's more the Latin language. :)

Comment: @chaos: I am quite aware of that. ;) Nevertheless it's the English language the word is used in.

Comment: @chaos how did that word end up in your vocabulary?

Comment: A friend of mine used it as an element of his merciless mocking of certain turns of phrase I would use.  I love it, of course.  It's like I always say: never use a big word where a diminutive lexeme will suffice.

Answer (score 15):

Holy overcomplexity, Batman.

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE (
    (name = "john doe") +
    (phone = "8183321234") +
    (email = "johndoe@yahoo.com") +
    (address = "330 some lane")
) >= 3;
```

Comment: +1 for the Batman comment. I'm not sure if that works, but it does, the +1 is well deserved anyways, as that is very neat. :)

Comment: Thank you kindly.  And of course it works; I never post SQL without testing it if I can help it.

Comment: I am still newb to SQL but I don't understand how that query does what it does.

Comment: Does (name = "john doe") return an int instead of a Boolean?

Comment: MySQL has no concept of 'booleans' as distinct from ints.  Even most language that do have such a concept allow evaluation of a boolean in numeric context, yielding 0 or 1 integer.

Comment: Thanks, I knew you could use 1 or 0 as a Boolean but I didn't know you could use a Boolean as a 1 or a 0 (If that makes sense).

Comment: So I noticed, if any of the values are NULL then it turns them all NULL. For example the first 3 matched, you would have 3 but if the last was NULL, it would return 3+NULL=NULL and you would not get anything returned when 3 indeed did match. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Wrap all the fields in `IFNULL`, e.g. `IFNULL(name, 0)`.

Answer (score 7):

Same thing using indexes:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    mytable _name
                WHERE   name = 'john doe'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  id
                FROM    mytable _name
                WHERE   phone = '8183321234'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  id
                FROM    mytable _name
                WHERE   email = "johndoe@yahoo.com"
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  id
                FROM    mytable _name
                WHERE   address = '330 some lane'
                ) q
        GROUP BY 
                id
        HAVING
                COUNT(*) >= 3
        ) di, mytable t
WHERE   t.id = di.id
```

See [**the entry in my blog**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/17/matching-3-of-4/) for performance details.

Comment: Tedious task, this up-voting business, I know. :-D

Comment: OBTW: Can you clarify whether or not indexes are used within CASE WHEN predicates? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. The indexes are not used. I'm going to make today's entry in my blog about this question, see there for details.

Answer (score 1):

I like the IF construct:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE
(    IF(name    = 'john doe', 1, 0) +
     IF(phone   = '8183311234', 1, 0) +
     IF(email   = 'johndoe@yahoo.com', 1, 0) +
     IF(address = '330 some lane', 1, 0)
) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Tomalak's query slightly so that it will use indexes if they are present. Although unless there is an index on each field, a full table scan will happen anyway.

```
SELECT
*, 
(
    IF(name="john doe", 1, 0) +
    IF(phone = "8183321234", 1, 0) +
    IF(email = "johndoe@yahoo.com", 1, 0) +
    IF(address = "330 some lane", 1, 0) 
) as matchCount
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
    name = "john doe" OR 
    phone = "8183321234" OR 
    email = "johndoe@yahoo.com" OR 
    address = "330 some lane"
HAVING matchCount >= 3
```

Comment: You need to indent code samples 4 spaces to make them display nicely. I made this change for you, hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: Mysql index merge performs worse than UNION ALL. See here: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/07/selecting-friends/

Comment: @Paolo how do you indent when you are typing code samples on here?

Comment: @John Isaacks: select a piece of code and press a 0100101 button above the edit field. The selected code will be indented with 4 spaces.

Comment: @John Isaacks: For copy/paste code samples, it helps to replace all tabs with spaces in a text editor beforehand, since tabs and spaces combined tend to blow the layout.